# Google Chrome cannot scroll after the recent update

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, scrollbar

My website was used to be working fine.   After chrome recent update, I can only scroll if I put my mouse on the scroll bar.  If I put my cursor on the content, it will not scroll. This problem also occurs on Opera Browser, but not an issue in IE or Firefox.

There is a post related with "Can't scroll on google chrome", but there is no answer suggested.

I bought the template online, and I have limited knowledge about coding.  I think I am not allowed to post my website link, so I will only provide css that is related with scrollbar.

```
.scroll{
width: 100%;
height: 75%;
overflow: scroll;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
.scroll{
width: 100%;
height: 70%;
overflow: scroll;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 12px;
background-color: rgba(156, 156, 156, .6);
}
```

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I have exactly the same problem...